# How to filter over a PrimeNg DataTable column with ng-template?

Tags: angular, primeng

**This is my column:**

```
<p-column header="Roles" sortable="true" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
  <ng-template let-user="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <div *ngFor="let role of user.roles">
      {{role.name}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Examples of user.roles JSON:

```
[ { "id": 3, "name": "A single role" } ]
[ { "id": 4, "name": "A role name" }, { "id": 6, "name": "Another role name" } ]
```

**I would like to add a filter on it - I tried adding this ng-template:**

```
<ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col let-test="rowData">
        <p-multiSelect [options]="roles" defaultLabel="All roles" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,test.roles,col.filterMatchMode)"
          styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-multiSelect>
 </ng-template>
```

The multiselect's options are in a separate roles array:

```
this.roles = [];
this.roles.push({ label: 'A role', value: 'aRole' });
this.roles.push({ label: 'Another role', value: 'anotherRole' });
```

... but for some reason, I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

- How can I achieve this ?
- How can I debug inline function calls like dt.filter($event.value,test.roles,col.filterMatchMode) ?
- I think that my main problem is that my column does not have a "field" value which can be used for filtering.

Comment: Can you update roles json response ?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: did you resolve this problem ? @Tim

Comment: No I did not...

Comment: just now post my answer check it. i hope it's useful for you

Comment: test.roles is undefined because roles is an array and cannot populate data for filtering. You might wanna try let-i="index" approach. Make this change afterwards: test.roles[i].name; I am on my phone so cannot test nor console.log anything. You can also tie another function to (onChange) to try logging your values.

Comment: I have same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the official forum, what I wanted is not possible. A "field" is required. As a workaround, I flattened my roles array into a string and displayed this in a field. I can now filter it with the matchmode "contains"

Comment: Could you explain your solution a bit further perhaps with an example?

Comment: I simply took the array I wanted to display and I joined all values into one comma separated String and I put it in the field of the datatable. It's not perfect, but it's enough for filtering...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

check your primeng node_module version am doing 4.2.1 primeng

**module.ts**

import DataTableModule and MultiSelectModule lik your app.module file

```
import { DataTableModule, MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        DataTableModule,
        MultiSelectModule
    ]
})
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    private users: Array<any> = [];
    private roles: Array<any> = [];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.users = [];
        this.users.push({ "id": 3, "name": "anotherRole" });
        this.users.push({ "id": 4, "name": "aRole" }, { "id": 6, "name": "anotherRole" });


        this.roles = [];
        this.roles.push({ label: 'A role', value: 'aRole' });
        this.roles.push({ label: 'Another role', value: 'anotherRole' });
    }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<p-dataTable [value]="users" [rows]="4" [paginator]="true" [globalFilter]="gb" #dt>
<p-header>List of Cars</p-header>
<p-column field="id" header="ID"></p-column>
<p-column field="name" header="Name" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="in">
    <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
        <p-multiSelect [options]="roles" defaultLabel="All Colors" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)" styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-multiSelect>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: I am not sure you understood what I wanted. My column does not have a filed (specifically because the value it is supposed to show is a (nested) array. The filter (and sort) function uses the value in the field to do comparing (as far as I understood)